# Continuous extension to extended reals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous periodic function such that $f$
extends to a continuous function from $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
Prove that $f$ is constant.

I already have a proof, but I feel like it's not as 'sleek' as it could be. Thus I want
to see how other people would prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say $T$ is the period of $f$. For any $r\in \mathbb R$, $$f(\infty)=\lim_nf(nT+r)=f(r).$$ So $f(x)=f(\infty)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.